# Disable noise cancellation iPhone 4 microphone

Tags: iphone, noise, noise-reduction

I would like to know if it's possible to disable the noise reduction microphone via code.

My app plays background music that gets trim off because of this new mic. So i would like to have the background noise mic disabled while my app is open and running.

Thank you

Comment: Have you able reduce the background noise while recording, any code would be more helpful.

Comment: I don't want to reduce the background noise. Fir my app I want to disable noise cancellation feature of the iPhone. Any solution for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Apple's Audio Unit Properties Reference document for the kAUVoiceIOProperty_BypassVoiceProcessing and kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingEnableAGC properties, and how to configure and/or change them.

Comment: thank you, I found AudioUnit a bit complex to handle. Do you have something easier I can start with? I'm starting from here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Hi can you please write some code with audioUnit object, i am not getting how to use kAUVoiceIOProperty_BypassVoiceProcessing for Simple AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: I am using `AVAudionRecorder` any idea where to set these properties so that I can programmatically disable noise cancellation feature of iPhone devices?

Answer (score 0):

The new mic should be active only during phone calls and not when your app is playing music. Are you sure this is the problem ??

Comment: Actually I would like to play some music while in a phone call.